# TypeORM: when do a findOneAndUpdate with option insert:true on MongoDB repository, the createdAt and updatedAt are never inserted, how to fix it?

Tags: mongodb, find, typeorm

I noticed that when I do a findOneAndUpdate with option insert:true on MongoDB repository which auto createAt and updateAt are enabled, the createdAt and updatedAt are never inserted/updated, is that normal? how to fix it?

do a findOne, if not found then create it else update the data. all that with the less DB requests sent

here an code example:

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
import { container, instanceCachingFactory } from 'tsyringe';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  EntityRepository,
  getCustomRepository,
  MongoRepository,
} from 'typeorm';
import { CreateDateColumn, ObjectIdColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

export abstract class TypeOrmAbstractEntity {
  @ObjectIdColumn() _id: ObjectID;
  @CreateDateColumn() createdAt: Date;
  @UpdateDateColumn() updatedAt: Date;

  get id() {
    return this._id.toHexString();
  }
}

@Entity('subscriptions')
export class Subscription extends TypeOrmAbstractEntity {
  @Column({ nullable: false }) subscriptionID: string;
  @Column({ nullable: false }) customerID: string;
}

@EntityRepository(Subscription)
export class SubscriptionRepository extends MongoRepository<Subscription> {}
container.register<SubscriptionRepository>(SubscriptionRepository, {
  useFactory: instanceCachingFactory(() =>
    getCustomRepository(SubscriptionRepository)
  ),
});

....

const stripeSubscriptionRepository = container.resolve(SubscriptionRepository);

subscriptionRepository.findOneAndUpdate(
  { customerID },
  {
    $set: {
      subscriptionID: subscription.id,
      customerID: customerID,
    },
  },
  { upsert: true }
);
```

Comment: Can't really tell you much about how to fix the code without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi @Joe, I updated the question content